# Fatal error: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException: Keyspace 'opspot' does not exist in

Tags: cassandra

Though I am using the **docker** facing this issue. The same things are working fine on other systems

> Fatal error: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException: Keyspace 'opspot' does not exist in /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php(32): Cassandra\DefaultCluster->connect('opspot') #1 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Data/DataProvider.php(38): Opspot\Core\Data\Cassandra\Client->__construct() #2 [internal function]: Opspot\Core\Data\DataProvider->Opspot\Core\Data{closure}(Object(Opspot\Core\Di\Di)) #3 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Di/Di.php(25): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Opspot\Core\Di\Di)) #4 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Blogs/Legacy/Repository.php(43): Opspot\Core\Di\Di->get('Database\Cassan...') #5 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Blogs/Repository.php(29): Opspot\Core\Blogs\Legacy\Repository->__construct() #6 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Blogs/Manager.php(46): Opspot\Core\Blogs\Repository->__construct() #7 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Blogs/Events.php(23): Opspot\Core\Blogs\Manager->__construct() #8 /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Eve in /var/www/Opspot/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php on line 32
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /var/www/Opspot/engine/lib/elgglib.php on line 985
>       An error occurred.
>       Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
>       Please try again later.

Comment: Add the related code in the question to get help!

Comment: Make sure the keyspace `opspot` is in the cassandra?